# Direct iPhone visitors to different stylesheet?

Tags: redirect, iphone

Is there a method whereby I can employ a different stylesheet (different to the style.css in my child theme) to visitors viewing on the iPhone?

Comment: @media css might be what your looking for

Answer (score 2):

There is a global `$is_iphone` variable, which you can check against in your code.

```
global $is_iphone;
if ( $is_iphone ) {
   // do something if $is_iphone is true
}
```

In the realm of your `style.css` however, I think `@media` queries may be easier. `style.css` is hard-coded as a required stylesheet, and there are no filters which can alter what the default stylesheet name is.

You can definitely use it for secondary stylesheets, however.

```
function my_iphone_styles() {
    global $is_iphone;
    if ( $is_iphone ) {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'my-iphone-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/iphone.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_iphone_styles' );
```

Comment: For anybody interested - it looks like WP has a few global browser detection variables: [Read Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Browser_Detection_Booleans)

Comment: No problem! Mark this question as answered, to help clean up the amount of unanswered questions out there. :)